# change url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to change your url (namely remove url parameters) with javascript without refreshing the page?

```
if ($(location).attr("href").substring("notSupported")) {
        var url = $(location).attr("href").match(".*index.action");
        window.location.assign(url[0]);
}
```

This works but since assign reloads the page, it goes into an infinite loop of reloads.  Help!

Comment: Yes, look at the HTML5 history API and `window.history`. Only works in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, you can push a history state with javascript.

```
if ($(location).attr("href").substring("notSupported")) {
    var url = $(location).attr("href").match(".*index.action");

    var currentState = history.state; // current page
    history.pushState(currentState , "Page Title", url[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change URL without reloading: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

with parameters: 
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/changing-url-in-the-address-bar-without-page-refresh

```
 var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
 history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Comment: Put a little more effort into it than just copying and pasting example code from a link you find. Address the OP's question, or solution.

Comment: effort is relative to the amount of effort to the question.. simple googling would find this exact problem lol.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use some sort of library such as AJAX as far as im aware to simply replace the current body with the loaded body ie as quoted before

> JQuery's Ajax functions are closely intertwined with the rest of the
>   functionality.
>
> There are a few other, stand-alone Ajax libraries around like Matt
>   Kruse's Ajax toolbox - maybe that helps.
>
> I would consider loading the full jQuery library. If you link to
>   jQuery on a CDN, loading times will be minuscule.

JQuery CDN (Include in script tag)
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

and then to load the page use

```
var url = "/page2.html";
$.ajax({url: url})
.done(function(data) {
$('#content').html(data);
});
```